# JIRA users without tasks

Tags: task, jira

How to get users without tasks on **Atlassian JIRA**?

It is necessary for an understanding of who is sitting without a subordinate tasks.

In JQL - i'm not found any operators like **GROUP or COUNT**

Answer (score 1):

There are no grouping functions in JQL, as it is not SQL. JQL translates directly to a Lucene query [terms & conditions apply].

I think the best way would be doing it in the DB, if you have access.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER_USER_NAME
FROM CWD_USER
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM JIRAISSUE WHERE ASSIGNEE = LOWER_USER_NAME )
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

You can filter it by group memberships, if you wish:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER_USER_NAME
FROM CWD_USER
INNER JOIN CWD_MEMBERSHIP ON LOWER_CHILD_NAME = LOWER_USER_NAME
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM JIRAISSUE WHERE ASSIGNEE = LOWER_USER_NAME )
AND LOWER_PARENT_NAME = 'lowercase-group-name-comes-here'
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Comment: A slightly detailed explanation how it happens: [JRA-19350](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-19350?focusedCommentId=560769&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-560769)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a possibility, see https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/304738/how-to-get-issue-count-using-jql-in-jira
You'll get a json response you can parse, but it's not a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, JQL doesn't do GROUP or COUNT. For smaller instances, you can use the Two Dimensional gadget on a JIRA dashboard to list Assignee vs Issue Types. This will then show a column for the Task issue type and you can see which users have no Tasks